# Images will be lost and blank when using the openseadragon filtering plug-in

Tags: javascript

I'm a user of openseadragon. When I use the openseadragon filtering plug-in, some images on the page will be lost and the blank console will output Ignoring tile 8/0_ 0 loaded before reset:xxx.jpg
like this
[image]

[image]

I have searched a lot. The openseadragon Filtering plug-in demo does not have this problem, but its demo does not have a solution to this problem
[demo](https://pages.nist.gov/OpenSeadragonFiltering/) I need help